# Datatables with Django

Tags: django, datatables

Has anyone tried to use DataTables with Django? I could not seem to get it to work, I had everything in the static files, etc..

Once I try and use datatables, I lose all the template styling and it just goes back to a default table.

**EDIT** There is not error when I load the page, all the data shows up just no template or datatables effects loading

This is the code:

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<script src="{% static "assets/js/jquery.datatables.js" %}" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="{% static "assets/js/jquery.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "assets/css/jquery.dataTables.css" %}" type="text/css"/>
<h1>Full list of supported Golf Courses:</h1>

<br>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#courses').dataTable();
    } );
</script> 
<table id="courses" class="display">
  <tr>
<th>Golf Course</th>
<th>Front 9</th>
<th>Back 9</th>
    <th>Total Par</th>
  </tr>
  {% for course_name, par_front_9, par_back_9, total_par in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ course_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ par_front_9 }}</td>
    <td>{{ par_back_9 }}</td>
    <td>{{ total_par }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you try to find out why this happens? Any error on Django's console? Any error on browser's error console?

Comment: See edit above, there are no errors

Comment: Your `<link>` tag is supposed to be inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I moved the <link> tag to base.html within the head tags and still no change to the format

Comment: Could you try moving the <script> tag for datatables after the script tag for jquery?

Comment: No change still, but good thought!

Comment: Looks like the CSS is atleast working, I applied the "smoothness theme" and it made the table a little more spread out.

Comment: Your table is badly formatted BTW. http://www.datatables.net/usage/

Comment: More CSS is working after proper formatting. No JS is working as of yet though

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, noticed that the code worked when removing {% extend "base.html" %}. Fixed it by using {% include "base.html" %}

Comment: Extend and include does different jobs. I wonder what you did for them to be interchangeable.